# ANTLR Python parser error

Tags: python, antlr4

I try to read a antlr grammar with python.

As in this question:

[Umlauts in JSON files lead to errors in Python code created by ANTLR4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44194089/umlauts-in-json-files-lead-to-errors-in-python-code-created-by-antlr4)

the error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/antlr4/Lexer.py", line 109,     
  in nextToken
    tokenStartMarker = self._input.mark()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mark'
```

occurs.

My grammar works fine with java and has no german umlauts.

The code is generated like this:

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python2 -visitor MyGrammar.g4
```

Could the error have another reason? Maybe version problems
or anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for getting this issue is because, you have not used antlr4.InputStream
The mark function is part of the InputStream class

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Python2/src/antlr4/InputStream.py

The following code works

**GRAMMAR FILE**

```
    grammar someGrammar;

    operation  : NUMBER '+' NUMBER ;

    NUMBER     : [0-9]+ ;

    WHITESPACE : ' ' -> skip ;
```

**PYTHON CODE**

```
    import antlr4
    from antlr4 import *
    from psqlListener import psqlListener
    from psqlLexer import psqlLexer
    from psqlParser import psqlParser
    import sys
    inputStream = antlr4.InputStream('4+5');
    lexer = psqlLexer(inputStream)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = psqlParser(stream)
```